# I cant find the names of paint properties in the documentation of the paint class in Kotlin

Tags: class, kotlin, documentation, paint

So I found this Example: https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/variable-shadowing-and-the-proper-use-of-apply/1407

Various ways of changing different Properties of a Paint object are presented. It seems, that in Kotlin it is convenient to use the apply function...

```
fun makePaint1(_color: Int, _textSize: Float, _strokeWidth: Float, _isAntiAlias: Boolean) =
        Paint().apply {
            color = _color
            isAntiAlias = _isAntiAlias
            textSize = _textSize
            strokeWidth = _strokeWidth
        }
```

But now my question: I would have assumed that there exists a list with all the property Names like:
"color"
"isAntiAlias"
"textSize"
"strokeWidth"
(I hope they are called property names)

But in the documentation of the Paint Class...(https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/graphics/Paint#ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG:kotlin.Int)
... when you look for example for "strokeWidth". You only find the two public methods getStrokeWidth() and setStrokeWidth() and neither description actually mentions the name "strokeWidth".

Does such a list of the names of class properties exist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kotlin has a thing called *property access syntax*, which basically means it translates getter and setter methods (like `getStrokeWidth()` and `setStrokeWidth()` so they look like a property - a field you can read and write like any `val` or `var`. It will usually complain if you don't use this!

So no, those properties don't actually exist on the `Paint` class - they're just sugar, generated from any `getThing` methods that exist (and they're writeable if `setThing` also exists).

It will do the same for some others too, like `isDither()` (*isThing*) which is a getter that returns a boolean. The equivalent setter is `setDither(boolean)` but Kotlin creates an `isDither` property you can read and write. And you'll see the same for things with `put()` and `get()` methods - you're encouraged to access them like an array, so `collection[item]` instead of `collection.get(item)`.